# Remove certain lines (with ---- and empty lines) from txt file using readLines() or read_lines()

Tags: r, text-files, readline, readr

**I have this text file called `textdata.txt`**:

```
TREATMENT DATA

------------------------------------
A: Text1
B: Text2

C: Text3
D: Text4

E: Text5
F: Text6
G: Text7
```

**I would like to remove the whole line with `---------` and the empty lines using `readLines` or `read_lines`**:

When I use `readLines("textdata.txt")` I get:

```
 [1] "TREATMENT DATA"                      
 [2] ""                                    
 [3] "------------------------------------"
 [4] "A: Text1"                            
 [5] "B: Text2"                            
 [6] ""                                    
 [7] "C: Text3"                            
 [8] "D: Text4"                            
 [9] ""                                    
[10] "E: Text5"                            
[11] "F: Text6"                            
[12] "G: Text7"
```

I would like to have, **expected output**:

```
 [1] "TREATMENT DATA"                      
 [2] "A: Text1"                            
 [3] "B: Text2"                                                               
 [4] "C: Text3"                            
 [5] "D: Text4"                                                             
 [6] "E: Text5"                            
 [7] "F: Text6"                            
 [8] "G: Text7"
```

Background:
I have de facto no experience handling files with R. The basic idea is to get a .txt format from which I can load multiple text files stored in a folder to one dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) read.table** If we can assume that the only occurrence of `-` is where shown in the question and if `?` does not occur anywhere in the file then this will read in the data regarding every line as a single field and throwing away the header.  Since `-` is the comment character lines with only `-` are regarded as blank and those will be thrown away. This reads the file into a one columnn data frame and the [[1]] returns that column as a character vector. If you want to keep the header omit header=TRUE.

```
read.table("myfile", sep = "?", comment.char = "-", header = TRUE)[[1]]
```

**2) grep** Another possibility is to read in the file and then remove lines that are empty or contain only `-` characters.

```
grep("^-*$", readLines("myfile"), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

**3) pipe** We could process the input using a filter and then pipe that into R.  On Windows `grep` is found in `C:\Rtools40\usr\bin` if you have Rtools40 installed but if it is not on your path either use the complete path or if you don't have it at all replace `grep` with `findstr`.  If on UNIX/Linux the escaping may vary according to which shell you are using.

```
readLines(pipe('grep -v "^-*$" myfile'))
```